# Multiple file drag and drop areas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to extend the code found [here](http://hayageek.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-jquery/); I want to have several boxes that are dropped in, and use the id of the box to sort the files depending on which box they are dropped in.

I added a second box, added the class, and changed the ID:

```
<div class="DropBox" id="Box1">Drag & Drop Files Here</div>
<div class="DropBox" id="Box2">Drag & Drop Files Here</div>
```

I changed the file upload to use the id:

```
function handleFileUpload(files,obj)
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
       {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('fileName', files[i]);
            //Set any additional file info here. 
            fd.append('folder', obj.id);


            var status = new createStatusbar(obj); //Using this we can set progress.
            status.setFileNameSize(files[i].name,files[i].size);
            sendFileToServer(fd,status);

       }
    }
```

And I used a loop for the drop events:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.DropBox').each(function(i, obj) {
            //var obj = $("#Box1");
            obj.on('dragenter', function (e) 
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                obj.style.border('2px solid #0B85A1');
            });

            obj.on('dragover', function (e) 
            {
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 e.preventDefault();
            });

            obj.on('drop', function (e) 
            {

                 obj.style.border('2px dotted #0B85A1');
                 e.preventDefault();
                 var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

                 //We need to send dropped files to Server
                 handleFileUpload(files, obj);
            });

            $(document).on('dragenter', function (e) 
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $(document).on('dragover', function (e) 
            {
              e.stopPropagation();
              e.preventDefault();
              obj.style.border('2px dotted #0B85A1');
            });

            $(document).on('drop', function (e) 
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    });
```

The drops no longer work though, the css doesn't even change the border on dragover. How can I fix this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to perform a loop to apply the handlers. Get rid of the each and change it back to

```
var obj = $(".Droppable");
```

jQuery will apply the event handler to all objects returned by your selector.

Comment: Okay that does fix that problem, but do you know why I'm getting `Box1` on both for line `fd.append('folder', obj.attr('id'));`

Comment: I had typed something about using $(this) when I posted the answer, but apparently forgot to hit Save during my edit. :)